# Same message appearing in different commands

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm having a problem with this discord bot where the same message is appearing in two different commands. Here's the code. In this case the problem is the sentence "You are already an admin", on the bottom part of the code. And that same sentence is appearing in the command !ping, up the top of the code. If anyone could help me, I would really appreciate that since I am quite new to programming.

Thanks!

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.upper().startswith('!PING'):
        userID = message.author.id
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "<@%s> Pong!" % (userID))
    if message.content.upper().startswith('!SAY'):
        if message.author.id == "218895918416658432":
            args = message.content.split(" ")
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "%s" % (" 
    ".join(args[1:])))
    else:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Insufficient 
permissions!")
    if message.content.upper().startswith('!AMIADMIN'):
        if "517064875134943262" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "You are an admin!")
        else:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "You are not an admin")
    contents = message.content.split(" ")
    for word in contents:
        if word.upper() in chat_filter:
            if not message.author.id in bypass_list:
                try:
                    await client.delete_message(message)
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, "**Hey!** You 
cannot use this word!")
                except discord.errors.NotFound:
                    return

    if message.author == client.user:
    return
    if message.content.upper().startswith('!ROLE ADMIN'):
        role = get(message.server.roles, id="517064875134943262")
        userID = message.author.id
    if not "343249790047485952" in [role.id for role in 
message.author.roles]:
        return
    elif "517064875134943262" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'You are already an admin 
    <@%s>' % (userID))
    else:
        await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Admin given to <@%s>' % 
    (userID))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your "if" statements at the bottom. At your code here:

```
if message.content.upper().startswith('!ROLE ADMIN'):
    role = get(message.server.roles, id="517064875134943262")
    userID = message.author.id
if not "343249790047485952" in [role.id for role in 
message.author.roles]:
    return
elif "517064875134943262" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
    await client.send_message(message.channel, 'You are already an admin 
    <@%s>' % (userID))
else:
    await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Admin given to <@%s>' % 
    (userID))
```

the problem is that with every message that comes through your bot is checking the roles of the user and returning a the message with any message that comes through. So instead move your last "if" "elif" and "else" statement to be under the main !ROLE ADMIN "if" statement like so:

```
if message.content.upper().startswith('!ROLE ADMIN'):
    role = get(message.server.roles, id="517064875134943262")
    userID = message.author.id
    if not "343249790047485952" in [role.id for role in 
message.author.roles]:
        return
    elif "517064875134943262" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'You are already an admin 
    <@%s>' % (userID))
    else:
        await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Admin given to <@%s>' % 
    (userID))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped me so much. :D

Comment: No problem! Really watch for indentation and logic blocks in python or they'll get you :)